# How to show loading spinner after click on add to cart button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes

WooCommerce has a known delay to add a product to cart.

Based on that, the official **[StoreFront](https://br.wordpress.org/themes/storefront/)** Theme for WooCommerce has a “**spinner**” after clicking on the purchase button.

[image][image]

However, the same doesn’t happen with **[ShopIsle](https://br.wordpress.org/themes/shop-isle/)** theme:

[image]

How to activate the spinner in ShopIsle?

Comment: I just downloaded shopisle to have a look and its heavily modified do you happen to have a link to the site online anywhere so I can find where the code is you would need to change ?

Comment: @BenCasey, sure: https://sandbox.rogeriodec.com.br/loja/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the button is clicked it is given a class of `loading` which doesn't appear to be handled.

You will have to find an icon in an iconfont (preferebly already loaded in your site i think its loading `glyphicons`) to use and add some css like below (Not tested, modify to suit)

Let me know if that helps.

```
button.add_to_cart_button.loading:after{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
    content: "\e031";
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7 );
    text-align:center;
    line-height:34px;
}
```

Comment: I did another approach, but the fact you have discovered the way to solve this, you deserve an award! Thank you very much!